# DCPError Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically: The objective is not DCP

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I try to solve the bellow convex problem:
[image]

In my opinion, the objective is convex.
[image]
my code is:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

ppMax = 1
Tmax  = np.array([1.19, 1.99, 4.16, 1.98, 2.53])
d     = np.array([2648000, 5552000, 4744000, 4056000, 6168000])
p     = np.array([0.19952623149688797, 0.00018021843172751523, 0.0020210434604112652, 0.001602417432034276, 0.003647501823979989])
r     = np.array([8574212.020483451, 6619470.077787987, 7521159.373986546, 7135440.631765847, 6832684.423897811])
c     = np.array([430000000.0, 700000000.0, 400000000.0, 220000000.0, 170000000.0])
fc    = np.array([40000000000, 40000000000, 40000000000, 40000000000, 40000000000])
ff    = np.array([4000000000, 4000000000, 4000000000, 4000000000, 4000000000])
W     = np.array([0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5])
wt    = np.array([0.609, 0.04000000000000001, 0.255, 0.308, 0.43])
we    = np.array([4.336742687028045, 10.647756980938421, 8.263103073749088, 7.675258157093112, 6.322105707432189])

pp = cp.Variable(len(Tmax))
cons = [cp.sum(pp) <= ppMax, d/r+c/fc+d/(W*cp.log(1+pp)) <= Tmax]
object = cp.Minimize(wt*(2*d/r+c/ff+c/fc+d/(W*cp.log(1+pp)))+we*(2*p*(d/r)+pp*(d/(W*cp.log(1+pp)))))
prob = cp.Problem(object, cons)

prob.solve()
print(prob.value, pp.value)
```

Comment: The first term might work using ``cp.inv_pos(cp.log(1+pp))`` . But the second term, which essentially contains a function of the form ``pp/log(1+pp)`` (modulo some positive constants), is concave and not convex.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplined-convex-programming